# Sorting a list with dictionaries, django

Tags: python, django, list, sorting, dictionary

myFrom two models in django i have created a list of dictionarys where each dictonary is a row in a table I show in the client.

I would like to be able to sort this list for each of the different "columns".

```
objdict = []    
mydict = {
    'thing1': model1.val1,
    'thing2': model2.val1,
    'thing3': model2.val2,
    'thing4': model1.val2,
    'thing5': model1.val3,
}
objdict.append(mydict)
```

Say i would like to sort this list on thing1 in ascending order.
How could I be able to acheive this?

Comment: `sorted(objdict, key=operator.itemgetter('thing1'))`?

Comment: Don't shadow the builtin ``dict`` constructor function.

Comment: No it didn't work, the function this sort is supposed to be in crashed and threw an exception.

Comment: @JamesMills Sorry I don't understand what shadow the builtin dict mean. Could you be more specific? Never I saw my mistake now. Now calling it mydict.

Comment: @Eitre, He simply means that don't use `dict` as a variable name, since `dict` has a special meaning in python syntax.

Comment: I think that's just a typo. Change: `objdict.append(dict)` to: `objdict.append(mydict)`

Comment: Yes i fixed that in my code but forgot to edit it here @Brandon

Comment: I can't seem to get anything out of `test = sorted(objdict, key=operator.itemgetter('thing1'))`
`print(test)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to do:

```
sorted_objects = sorted(objdict, key=lambda k: k['thing1'])
```

will get you ascending order. For descending:

```
sorted_objects = sorted(objdict, key=lambda k: k['thing1'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Yes i think that works. How do i do descending as well?

Comment: I've added an example of descending order.